# How to split the string in the list?

Tags: python

I am handing with the txt dataset, the slash words are codes, I used this code to convert the trans.txt into CSV format

```
import pandas as pd
trans=pd.read_csv("trans.txt",header=None,sep=' ')

#Then I used the code to find the values

trans_values=trans.values


# The values' output looks like this array
   ([['0,1,2'],
   ['3'],
   ['4,3'],
   ...,
   ['762'],
   ['775'],
   ['789']], dtype=object)

#I tried to convert this array to a list.

trans_values_list=trans_values.tolist()
```

The first array is ['0,1,2'], but I want the arrays to look like something like ['0','1','2'], how could I split the strings inside the list? Need it as it is needed to finish the apriori problem, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def split_by_comma(data) :
   data_in_required_format = []
   for i in range(len(data)) :
      data_in_required_format.append(data[i][0].split(','))
   return data_in_required_format
```

so if you pass a list **data = ([['0,1,2'],['3'], ['4,3'],['762'],['775'],['789']])**

This will return the following output

output = [['0', '1', '2'], ['3'], ['4', '3'], ['762'], ['775'], ['789']]

Answer (score 0):

Just write below code

```
for i, val in enumerate(trans_value_list):
    trans_value_list[i] = val[0].split(",")
```